# IAM Roles and instance profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a question about application access Dynamo DB tables.

If I create a Role to allow application to access DynamoDB tables, can I associate the role to the application instances by referencing a instance profile?

Answer (score 1):

You would assign the instance profile to the EC2 server at the time the server is created. Then any application running on that server will have the correct role to access the DynamoDB tables.

Note that you can not assign a role to an EC2 instance that has already been created. However you can modify the role after the server has started.